# Check positive linear combination of 2 dimensional vectors

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, linear-algebra

I have three vectors in the plane and I want to check if the third is a positive linear combination of the other two as fast as possible.
that is if y = ax + bz, I want to check if both a and b are positive.
If x and z are orthogonal I could of course just check the scalar products  and . But in this case they are not. Is there a quicker way then solving the linear system?
Sure I could solve the linear system in closed form.
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? How did that work? How *didn't* it work? Is there something specific problem you need help with? Because right now your question is on the path to be closed. If you haven't done so yet, please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: You might also want to read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the vector product with `z`:

```
y^z = a x^z + b z^z 
    = a x^z            // since z^z = 0

a   = y^z / x^z
```

So `a` is positive if `signum(y^z) == signum(x^z)`.

Likewise, `b` is positive if `signum(x^y) == signum(x^z)`.

The (orthogonal component of) the vector product of `x = (x0,x1)` and `y = (y0,y1)` is

```
x^y = x0*y1 - x1*y0
```